# How to create a YUI3 DataTable with complex JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, datatable, yui, yui3

I'm fairly new to YUI and facing an issue while trying to create a YUI3 DataTable from the below JSON -

{

```
    "generations": [

    {
        "type": "Modern",
        "showName": "The Modern Generation",
        "imgURI": "file:/D:/projectGen.png",
        "relations": {
            "father": {
                "age": "49",
                "firstName": "George",
                "lastName": "Mathews",
                "priority": "1",
                "profession": "Service"
            },
            "mother": {
                "age": "47",
                "firstName": "Susan",
                "lastName": "Aldrin",
                "priority": "2",
                "profession": "Home-Maker"
            },
            "brother": {
                "age": "28",
                "firstName": "Martin",
                "lastName": "Mathews J",
                "priority": "3",
                "profession": "Engineer"
            },
            "sister": {
                "age": "23",
                "firstName": "Laura",
                "lastName": "Mathews J",
                "priority": "4",
                "profession": "Fashion Model"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

The table which I need to create should look like the one below -

[image]

Any info on how can I do this?
A JSFiddle would be appreciated.

Comment: Can someone help me with this. Can @Aditya help me?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818537/yui3-datatable-with-complex-json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this helps. http://jsfiddle.net/BM3kX/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="yui3-skin-sam" id="datatable"></div>​
```

Javascript:

```
YUI().use('datatable', 'datasource-local', 'datasource-jsonschema',function(Y){
    var data  = {};//JSON here
    var localDataSource = new Y.DataSource.Local({source:data});
    localDataSource.plug(Y.Plugin.DataSourceJSONSchema, {
        schema: {
            resultListLocator: 'generations',
            resultFields: [{key:'showName'},
                           {
                               key:'father',
                               locator:'relations.father.firstName'
                           },
                           {
                               key:'mother',
                               locator:'relations.mother.firstName'
                           },
                           {
                               key:'brother',
                               locator:'relations.brother.firstName'},
                           {
                               key:'sister',
                               locator:'relations.sister.firstName'
                           }]
        }
    });
    var table = new Y.DataTable({
        columns: ["showName", "father","mother","brother","sister"]
    });

    table.plug(Y.Plugin.DataTableDataSource, {
        datasource: localDataSource
    });

    table.render('#datatable');
    table.datasource.load();

});​
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch Stacy. That was quick!

In the meantime, I missed to mention the point of creating the DataTable dynamically. How can we make this more generalized by creating the columns dynamically?

Let's assume that I have to display the 'firstName' attribute for each relations object. Can you help?

Comment: Hi Aditya

Would this be solving the case of the dynamic columns? http://jsfiddle.net/BM3kX/3/

Comment: That seems nice.

What if we don't know how many objects the 'relations' contains. In the example JSON I mentioned, there were only 4 objects - father, mother, brother and sister. It may happen that there are more or less than that. What should be the schema in such cases?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! :)

Would you recommend any learning material on YUI3?

Comment: yes the yui cookbook http://www.amazon.com/YUI-3-Cookbook-Cookbooks-OReilly/dp/1449304192. You can also check out www.youtube.com/yuilibrary and ofcourse the user guides (http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/guides/).

Comment: Hey Stacy,
I was wondering how could I set the "profession" values as column names. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Can someone help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818537/yui3-datatable-with-complex-json